# Where is the way on a rotating black hole to another Universe?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, wormholes, kerr-metric

Where is the way on a [rotating](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotating_black_hole) black [hole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerr_metric) to another Universe? Where and how should it be entered by to get away from here?

Comment: Who says there is another universe that we can get to?

Comment: @KyleKanos He: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roy_Kerr

Comment: Kerr black holes have not been proven to exist, so it's pure speculation.

Comment: @KyleKanos Ok, I understood. But if we assume he has right, what is the answer?

Comment: I can't answer speculative questions.

Comment: @KyleKanos A conditional answer were for me just so good.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about speculative physics and requires an in-depth explanation of the Kerr metric which makes it partially too broad and partially non-mainstream.

Comment: @Brandon Enright : While I agree that to answer this question would be pure speculation, I absolutely disagree that the Kerr Metric is non-mainstream.
It is a well studied solution to the Einstein equations which is to be found in any graduate lecture course on Black Hole Mechanics. See [Cambridge](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/hsr1000/teaching.html) for example.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Entering a black hole, jumping into another universe---with questions](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/19636/entering-a-black-hole-jumping-into-another-universe-with-questions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The singularity in the Kerr-BH has the form of a ring. This ring is in the event horizon, although if the BH rotates enough fast, it could be out of it, which were nonsense.

Some interesting happens if you are going through this ring.

Comment: An incomplete answer... Could you elaborate?