# Black hole surrounded by black holes

Tags: black-holes

Is there any configuration of black holes that surround a central black hole that could lift it out of the singularity due to net effects on space-time? Perhaps a sphere of black holes of equal mass placed at equidistant points around it could smooth out the enclosed space-time?

Comment: Can I suggest changing the question to (also) ask if a black hole can exist inside a black hole ?  I think this may also be a way to look at what you may be thinking about.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A Sphere of Black Holes](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/132195/)