# Are black holes the edge of our universe?

Tags: cosmology, black-holes, spacetime, universe, event-horizon

Are black holes the actual edge of the universe? Because spacetime is another dimension, I would assume the universe doesn’t have perceived corners or edges. At least humans cannot perceive it.
The edges are the black holes scattered across the universe. Is that right?

Comment: *Spacetime is another dimension.* What do you mean? We live in spacetime.

Comment: Right. So we are not just in a 3d space. Theoretically, in a 3d space, there can be perceived edges or corners. Because we live in spacetime there is no edge I was thinking since the laws of physics breakdown in blackholes, that’s “edge”

Comment: What do you mean there is no edge? That makes no sense. What does edges have anything to do with dimensions?

Comment: The question [Entering a black hole, jumping into another universe](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/19636/entering-a-black-hole-jumping-into-another-universe-with-questions) is not exactly a duplicate but it is very closely related.

Answer (score 1):

> Are black holes the edge of our universe ?

No, at least not in the way that physicists and mathematicians understand an edge ("boundary" would be a more technical term). An edge or boundary to a surface is something that cannot be crossed without leaving the surface - but we know that the event horizon of a black hole can be crossed. We can even define a spacetime co-ordinate system which is smooth at the event horizon, so the event horizon is not even like a "crease" in spacetime.

It is true that we don't know what happens at the centre of a black hole because our current theories of physics break down at that point (which is popularly called the black hole's singularity) - but that is a shortcoming of our current physics. We still have no reason to think that there is an "edge" to spacetime anywhere inside a black hole.

Comment: I did some research and found this on an article from old Harvard article. What do they mean ? 
“A black hole is a true "hole" in space: Anything that crosses the edge of the hole - called the "horizon" of the hole - is swallowed forever. For this reason, black holes are considered an edge of space, a one-way exit door from our universe; nothing inside a black hole can ever communicate with our universe again, even in principle.” I’ll post the link if needed . Idk if I can or allowed

Comment: Thanks btw for the answer. So according to the article it could be considered the edge of space. But yeah I guess I was talking about spacetime. If space and time flip in a black hole, is that not considered a boundary? Wouldn’t that be the end of spacetime as we know it?