# Another universe in the other side of a black hole?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, wormholes, white-holes

A common notion is that there is another universe in the other side of a black hole, past the singularity point....is this true?  does it have any scientific support?

Comment: Duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/45876/50583

Comment: Other possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/7005/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19636/2451 and links therein.